Android app Crashing due to GestureHandlerRootView
Help me To fix these issues ONlY android Side
Android app Crashing due to GestureHandlerRootView
explain reason if possible
other imports...
import Header from '../../Components/Header';
import {
  GestureDetector,
  Gesture,
  GestureHandlerRootView,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';

function ContactUs({navigation}) {
  const [swipeData, setSwipeData] = React.useState('Swipe Please');
  let startX = 0;

  const tap = Gesture.Pan()
    .onBegin(e => {
      startX = e.x;
      console.log('Gesture started at:', startX);
    })
    .onUpdate(e => {
      const deltaX = e.x - startX;
    })
    .onEnd(e => {
      const deltaX = e.x - startX;
      if (deltaX > 50) {
        setSwipeData('left to right');
        console.log('Scrolled from left to right');
      } else if (deltaX < -50) {
        setSwipeData('right to left');
        console.log('Scrolled from right to left');
      } else {
        setSwipeData("Not enough Swiped || It's horizontal movement");
        console.log("Not enough Swiped || It's horizontal movement");
      }
      console.log('Gesture ended at:', e.x, 'with deltaX:', deltaX);
    })
    .onFinalize(() => {
      startX = 0;
    });

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex:1}}>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <Header canGoBack={true} />
        <GestureDetector gesture={tap}>
          <Animated.View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
            }}>          
            <Text>{swipeData}</Text>
          </Animated.View>
        </GestureDetector>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
}

export default ContactUs;

Just Willing to update state based on swipe Gesture
issue Occurs Only android side but IOS is Perfectely fine

Could you share the Issues or crash detail

I do Open Android logcat  and search for and crash, But No authentic OR Detail message is Provided
